# Como puedo guardar al local storage información de una api cuando haga click a un h2, si es un nodeList y no funciona al hacer clic? en javascript

Tags: javascript, api

```
let titulosPersonajes = document.querySelectorAll('h2');
let apiPersonajes = "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/2"
fetch(apiPersonajes)
.then((response => response.json()))
.then((data) => {
    let valorData = data.id
    console.log(valorData)
    let valorName = data.name
    let valorGender = data.gender
    let valorSpecies = data.species
    let valorStatus = data.status
    const insertId = () => {
        window.localStorage.setItem('Id' , valorData);
        console.log("insertado el id");
    }
    const insertName = () => {
        window.localStorage.setItem('Nombre' , valorName);
    }
    const insertGender = () => {
        window.localStorage.setItem('Genero' , valorGender);
    }
    const insertSpecies = () => {
        window.localStorage.setItem('Especie' , valorSpecies);
    }
    const insertStatus = () => {
        window.localStorage.setItem('Estado' , valorStatus);
    }  
titulosPersonajes.forEach((titulo) => {
    titulo.addEventListener('click', insertId);
    titulo.addEventListener('click', insertName);
    titulo.addEventListener('click', insertGender);
    titulo.addEventListener('click', insertSpecies);
    titulo.addEventListener('click', insertStatus);
})
});
```

Esto es lo que he intentado, la api de los personajes esta hardcoded de momento para que yo al pulsar al h2 de ese personaje que tengo en mi HTML me almacene su id,nombre,genero,especie y estado.
Aqui un ejemplo visual:
[HTML de mi proyecto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoMGl.png)

He probado el codigo de muchas formas realmente nose hacer el cambio del h2 de cada personaje que lo sepa interpretar mis inserts

Comment: No se entiende, debes explicar mejor el resultado esperado y/o el error que tienes. Además agrega el HTML

Comment: Hola buenas, mis disculpas es mi primer por aquí. Te dejo mi HTML y basicamente la funcionalidad que quiero sacarle a esto es que al hacer click a h2 del tiutlo de x personaje de la API lo almacene por window.local.storage para asi con esa información guardada tenerlo como en una especie de sección de favoritos que consta de si he hecho click  en uno de estos, se almacena en favoritos.

Answer (score 0):

Tu página se va generando mediante javascript al consumir los datos de una API. Un problema habitual en esto casos es el uso de `addEventListener` para añadir eventos a elementos que entran y salen en el DOM, porque estos eventos se pierden.

Para estos casos, yo te recomiendo usar el atributo `onclick`, por ejemplo en tu `h2`

```
<h2 onclick="funcion(argumentos)">Nombre</h2>
```

Con esto solucionas de golpe el problema.

Luego está el tema del `localStorage`, este funciona como un diccionario, es decir tiene un par `clave/valor`, si tu asignas como clave "id" solo puedes guardar un valor bajo esa clave, no puedes repetirla. Yo entiendo que quieres guardar varios personajes como favoritos, entonces de esa manera no te sirve.

Lo que puedes hacer es guardar un objeto en formato JSON, bajo la clave "favoritos". Este objeto puedes hacerlo funcionar como otro diccionario, donde la clave será la id del personaje y el valor las propiedades que deseas guardar.

Aquí un ejemplo

*(Advertencia: En el Snippet de SOes no funciona el localStorage, pero el código ha sido validado)*

```js
fetch("https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character").then(a=>a.json())
.then(ImprimirPersonajes);

function ImprimirPersonajes(page){
   const contentPersonajes = document.getElementById("contentPersonajes");
   
   for(let p of page.results){
   
     const v = JSON.stringify({
       id:p.id,
       name:p.name,
       gender:p.gender,
       status:p.status,
       species:p.species
     });
    
     contentPersonajes.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",
     `<div>
       <img src="${p.image}">
       <h2 onclick='SavePersonaje(${v})'>${p.name}</h2>
       <div>${p.status}</div>
     </div>
     `)
   }
}

function SavePersonaje(personaje){
    let fav= JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("favoritos") ?? "{}");
    fav[personaje.id] = personaje;
    window.localStorage.setItem("favoritos",JSON.stringify(fav));
}

function verFav(){
  let fav= JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("favoritos") ?? "{}");

  for(var p of Object.values(fav)){
      console.log(p);
  }
}
```

```css
#contentPersonajes{
 display:grid;
 grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(300px, 1fr));
}

#contentPersonajes h2{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="verFav()">Ver favoritos</button>
<div id="contentPersonajes"></div>
```

Comment: Menos mal mencionaste que sos vos quien recomienda el `onclick`, ya que desde hace tiempo [se desaconseja su uso](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these).

Comment: (Sé que lo sabés porque ya lo debatimos hace tiempo, pero otros no lo saben) :)

Comment: @padaleiana Y sigo en desacuerdo :D.  En MDN no da ningún motivo sustancial para desaconsejar su uso y menos en este caso particular donde el botón se crea a partir de JS

Comment: El pequeño problema que tengo es que no me dejan manipular el html ni el css de la web. Voy a probar a hacerlo todo con js

Comment: @Moisés no te entiendo